# My mouse sensitivity goes crazy in CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, mouse

I've been playing **CS:GO** for a while now and I've had countless problems that I have come across and have had to fix, which is a real shame because its a great game.

Anyway, what happens is that when I move the mouse without pressing down any buttons on the mouse (right click, left click and the wheel button), the mouse works fine, but as soon as I press any one of these buttons the mouse goes crazy, like the sensitivity is 100x higher.

Can anyone think of a solution?

It's only on **CS:GO**, no other games and a few other people seem to be having the same problem.

Comment: What kind of mouse is it?

Comment: is it perhaps a razer ?

Comment: Im thinking it's a mouse software issue. perhaps your mouse keys are bound to mouse sensitivity? You can check this is the software for your mouse (different for every mouse).

Comment: @RustyMembers So do I think. Especially with Logitech I'd turn the software off.

Comment: I have one of those free mouses you get with dell... but ive never had any problems like this before and it doesnt affect me on any other game

Comment: I've also tried my wireless apple mouse as i have a mac but it still has the same problem

Comment: Please check for mouse acceleration in both windows and CS:GO settings. I heard that it can cause problems, too.

Comment: Yeah ive got it all turned off. i think the problem is to do with the game not binding the mouse to the centre of the screen after every tick maybe

Comment: Okay i fixed it. i just turned on raw input i the mouse settings

Answer (score 1):

The first and most obvious suggestion - make sure your drivers are up to date. You never know just when one driver goes on the fritz, so making sure that everything is up to date and working is always a good start.

Next, as suggested, make sure the buttons aren't bound to sensitivity commands, as that would cause you chaos.

If you have access to any other mice and the problem persists, try swapping the mice around to see if that makes any changes.

Answer (score 0):

To check if it is a bind problem open the console (tidle key) and type `bind mouse1`.  What should come up is do making along the lines of `"mouse1" = +attack` if there is anything else there then you found your problem. To solve this you would then type`bind mouse1 "+attack"